# what is best practice for feature scaling (Standardization) and LabelEncode and OneHotEncode data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

Here we have training data (x_train) and testing data (x_test) and all_data which combined with training and testing data

so if we do standardized about our data, which one do you think is the best practice?

suppose we are using pandas and sklearn

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

1. Do standardization on train data, and then apply to test data, and the
   code is:

> ```
> scaler.fit(x_train)
> x_train=scaler.transform(x_train)
> x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)
> ```

2. Do standardization on all_data, and then apply to train and test data, and the code is:

> ```
> scaler.fit(all_data)
> x_train=scaler.transform(x_train)
> x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)
> ```

the same question is about LabelEncoder and One-Hot encode categorical features, which method do you use?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Scaling should be done using situation 1 which is fitting the scaler only to you training set and then using that same same scaling on your test set.

Situation 2 where you fit on all the data is a form of *data snooping* where information from your test set is leaking into your training set. This can lead to very erroneous results. There is a [fantastic segment](http://work.caltech.edu/library/173.html) from Abu Mustafa's data learning class that covers this.

For label encoding, lets assume you create a binary column for each unique value in all the categorical columns. The columns that have categories that are in the test set but not in the training set will simply all be encoded as 0. Even if you decided to use label encoding for the entire training and test dataset together, when you build your model all the categories not in the training set will be set to 0 and not affect your model - the weight from these unknown categories will simply be added to a bias unit.

Answer (score 1):

In practical use, you cannot do the second.

Do not forget that cross-validation is only to estimate the error on *future* data, that you do not yet have.

This implies that you need to setup your scenario as closely to the real case as possible - i.e. **pretend the test data does not exist**.

Secondly, **including the test data in the normalization can cause overfitting**! For example, assume that you want to predict the stock value of a company. If you standardize using the whole series, then split, I can compare the mean on the training set with 0 to 'predict' if the stocks will go up or down. But facing real data, this fails - because the approach is overfitting to information you *leaked* from test into training.

As for binary attributes, normalization is even harder. **Do not assume standardization is good for encoded data** - the problem is that with the encoding you introduce *correlated* variables, and you end up giving too much weight to them by standardization.